# Unknown engine "name" while parsing selector name=startcreateddate createStackless in Playwright

Tags: python, automation, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-python

I have tried to identify the element using id or name in Playwright, but playwright throws an error:

`"Unknown engine "name" while parsing selector name=startcreateddate createStackless"`.

[image: error screen]

My code is:

```js
playwright.$("name=startcreateddate")
```

How can I select an element by Id or name in Playwright?

Comment: What HTML elements are you trying to select? Please share your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you're trying to select elements that look something like those in the following example, and doing it in the browser console during a debug session initiated by a Playwright Python script (based on your tag).

For selecting an element with an id:

```html
<p id="foo">hello</p>
```

use `playwright.$("#foo")`.

For selecting an element with a `name=` attribute:

```html
<input name="startcreateddate">
```

use `playwright.$('[name="startcreateddate"]')`.

The reason for the bizarre-looking error in your console is that `foo=` syntax is used to [set the selection engine](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#chaining-selectors), like `text=`, `css=` or `xpath=`. `name=` is not a valid engine option.

Here's a complete runnable example (you can paste the above commands into the browser console when it pauses on the breakpoint):

```py
from playwright.sync_api import expect, sync_playwright  # 1.37.0


html = """<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
<p id="foo">hello</p>
<input name="startcreateddate" value="world">
</body></html>"""


def main():
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=False)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.set_content(html)

        page.pause() # paste the code above into the browser console

        # just in case you want to see these selectors in Python...
        p = page.locator("#foo")
        date = page.locator('[name="startcreateddate"]')

        print(p.text_content())
        print(date.get_attribute("value"))

        expect(p).to_have_text("hello")
        expect(date).to_have_value("world")

        browser.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```